# Do backlinks from a widget in an iframe improve google rank?

Tags: seo, backlinks, iframe

Our competitor recently had a widget added to a third party website. They had a follow backlink on their logo until recently but have changed their code now I assume to abide by google best practices regarding widgets and backlinks.

[`https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66356?hl=en`](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66356?hl=en)

I have inserted the html of the widget below.

SEMRush has picked up 2.5k iframe backlinks that have high PA and DA scores for the domain of the competitor.

I'm wondering how much of an effect if any of the backlinks originally picked up by google when the widget did not include any no_follow in the meta content.

And also now that the meta content is set to no_follow will google eventually pick it up and remove the link juice from previous backlinks if any was prescribed in the first place.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>domain Widget</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    html, body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
  </style>
  <meta name="robots" content="nofollow" />
</head>
<body class="widget-iframe">
<!-- domain plan search widget -->
<div id="search-widget"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.domain.co.nz/widget/js/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  Widget.init({
    widgetSelector: '#search-widget',
    baseUrl: 'https://www.domain.co.nz',

  });
</script>
<!-- end widget -->

<!-- Metrics -->


<!-- end Metrics -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

From the example of above code, I will say your competitor will not get any benefits in ranking because of nofollow meta tags.

> And also now that the meta content is set to no_follow will google
>   eventually pick it up and remove the link juice from previous
>   backlinks if any was prescribed in the first place.

Yes, once they re crawl that webpage again.

Regarding scripts, I think google does not consider javascript source links as backlinks, they just use them to render webpages. The semrush tool might use different kind of webkit to render webpage. They may assign every source which contain http or https as backlinks, but that's not true. Google use same kind webkit as our browser use, while third party scrapper does not render the webpage as like our browser do, because it need more CPU resources.

Google said about widget links means when sidebar contain some widget with some anchor text like "powered by example.com " [Here is some good example given on Google official webmaster blog](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2016/09/a-reminder-about-widget-links.html). Generally that kind of links compress by Google, and pass very less value, but still it pass some link juicy hence it is consider as blackhat technique. But from your example code, I don't consider them as widget links.